# How to parse and edit haproxy config file using python

Tags: python, parsing, haproxy

I need tp parse and modify my `haproxy.cfg` file using python but using my current code its giving some error. I am explaining the error below.

```
Line 30: expected [^#\n], "#", [\n], [^#\n]
  server cfme2 10.16.79.63:30101  check backup inter 1s
```

I am explaining my code below.

> haproxy.cfg::

```
global
    log                 127.0.0.1 local0
    chroot              /var/lib/haproxy
    pidfile             /var/run/haproxy.pid
    maxconn         4000
    user                haproxy
    group               haproxy
    daemon
defaults
    mode                        http
    log                         global
    option                      httplog
    option                      dontlognull
    option             http-server-close
    option     forwardfor       except 127.0.0.0/8
    option                      redispatch
    retries                     3
    timeout http-request    10s
    timeout queue           1m
    timeout connect         10s
    timeout client              1m
    timeout server          1m
    timeout http-keep-alive     10s
    timeout check           10s
listen apache-30101
  bind 10.16.79.55:30101
  mode tcp
  balance source
  server cfme1 10.16.79.62:30101 check inter 1s
  server cfme2 10.16.79.63:30101  check backup inter 1s
```

The above one is my `haproxy.cfg` file and I need to edit this file.

> test.py::

```
from pyhaproxy.parse import Parser
from pyhaproxy.render import Render
import pyhaproxy.config as config


def editConfig():
    try:
        cfg_parser = Parser('haproxy.cfg')
        configuration = cfg_parser.build_configuration()
        print(configuration)
        for listen in configuration.listens:
            print(listen)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return None
```

Here my requirement is I need to change `server cfme1 10.16.79.62:30101 check inter 1s` to `server cfme1 10.16.79.62:30101 check backup inter 1s` and `server cfme2 10.16.79.63:30101  check backup inter 1s` to `server cfme2 10.16.79.63:30101  check inter 1s` so for that when I parsing the file I am getting the above error. If anybody has the correct solution to parse and modify this file as per my requirement will be great help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use TTP parser for this purpose. Please see the code I wrote to convert primary to secondary and vice versa. You can use similar template to edit you data.

```
from ttp import ttp
import json

data_to_parse = """
global
    log                 127.0.0.1 local0
    chroot              /var/lib/haproxy
    pidfile             /var/run/haproxy.pid
    maxconn         4000
    user                haproxy
    group               haproxy
    daemon
defaults
    mode                        http
    log                         global
    option                      httplog
    option                      dontlognull
    option             http-server-close
    option     forwardfor       except 127.0.0.0/8
    option                      redispatch
    retries                     3
    timeout http-request    10s
    timeout queue           1m
    timeout connect         10s
    timeout client              1m
    timeout server          1m
    timeout http-keep-alive     10s
    timeout check           10s
listen apache-30101
  bind 10.16.79.55:30101
  mode tcp
  balance source
  server cfme1 10.16.79.62:30101 check inter 1s
  server cfme2 10.16.79.63:30101  check backup inter 1s
"""

template_haproxy_cfg = """
<group name="HAPROXY_CFG">         
  server {{CFM}} {{IP}} {{check}} {{inter}} {{1s}}
</group>
<group name="HAPROXY_CFG"> 
  server {{CFM}} {{IP}}  {{check}} {{backup}} {{inter}} {{1s}}
</group>
"""

def haproxy_cfg_parser(data_to_parse): 
    ttp_template = template_haproxy_cfg

    parser = ttp(data=data_to_parse, template=ttp_template)
    parser.parse()

    # print result in JSON format
    results = parser.result(format='json')[0]
    #print(results)

    #converting str to json. 
    result = json.loads(results)

    return(result)

parsed_haproxy_cfg_parser = haproxy_cfg_parser(data_to_parse)

#print(parsed_haproxy_cfg_parser[0]['HAPROXY_CFG'])

for i in parsed_haproxy_cfg_parser[0]['HAPROXY_CFG']:
    #print(i)
    if 'backup' in i: # It gives information from backup server
        #print(i)
        print("The new primary:")
        print(f"server {i['CFM']} {i['IP']} {i['check']} {i['inter']} {i['1s']}") # backup converted to primary.
    elif 'backup' not in i: # It gives information from primary server
        #print(i)
        print("The new secondary:")
        print(f"server {i['CFM']} {i['IP']} {i['check']} backup {i['inter']} {i['1s']}") # primary converted to backup.
```

Please see the output:

[image]
[image]

EDITED with haproxy.cfg :

```
with open("haproxy.cfg") as f: # Your original data. 
    data_to_parse = f.read()

template_haproxy_cfg = """
<group name="HAPROXY_CFG">         
  server {{CFM}} {{IP}} {{check}} {{inter}} {{1s}}
</group>
<group name="HAPROXY_CFG"> 
  server {{CFM}} {{IP}}  {{check}} {{backup}} {{inter}} {{1s}}
</group>
"""

def haproxy_cfg_parser(data_to_parse): 
    ttp_template = template_haproxy_cfg

    parser = ttp(data=data_to_parse, template=ttp_template)
    parser.parse()

    # print result in JSON format
    results = parser.result(format='json')[0]
    #print(results)

    #converting str to json. 
    result = json.loads(results)

    return(result)

parsed_haproxy_cfg_parser = haproxy_cfg_parser(data_to_parse)

with open("haproxy.cfg") as f:
    haproxy = f.readlines()

counter_primary = False
counter_backup = False

for line in haproxy:
    #print(line)
    if "server cfme" in line:
        #print(line)
        for i in parsed_haproxy_cfg_parser[0]['HAPROXY_CFG']:
            #print(i)
            if 'backup' in i: # It gives information from backup server
                #print(i)
                print("The new primary:")
                print(f"server {i['CFM']} {i['IP']} {i['check']} {i['inter']} {i['1s']}") # backup converted to primary.
                new_primary = f"  server {i['CFM']} {i['IP']} {i['check']} {i['inter']} {i['1s']}\n"
                if counter_primary == False:
                    with open("desired_haproxy.cfg", "a") as f:
                        f.write(new_primary)
                counter_primary = True
            elif 'backup' not in i: # It gives information from primary server
                #print(i)
                print("The new secondary:")
                print(f"server {i['CFM']} {i['IP']} {i['check']} backup {i['inter']} {i['1s']}") # primary converted to backup.
                new_secondary = f"  server {i['CFM']} {i['IP']} {i['check']} backup {i['inter']} {i['1s']}\n"
                if counter_backup == False:
                    with open("desired_haproxy.cfg", "a") as f:
                        f.write(new_secondary)
                counter_backup = True
    elif "server cfme" not in line: 
        with open("desired_haproxy.cfg", "a") as f:
            f.write(line)

# "desired_haproxy.cfg" file should be opened which includes the converted data.
```

Comment: How I can use the config file as external file.

Comment: what do you mean by the external file?

Comment: the configuration file `i.e-haproxy.cfg`.

Comment: I think you can use "with open" to open data and convert it. I thought that you are only looking for a way to parse data. Anyway, I have edited my post, you can check it out.